# How to find percentage in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentage

```
maleWomanSurvey = survey[(survey.Gender == 'Man') | (survey.Gender == 'Woman')]
maleWomanSurvey[maleWomanSurvey.Occupation == 'Currently not employed'].groupby('Gender').size()*100/maleWomanSurvey.groupby('Gender').size()
```

I want to find percentage of currently not employed males and females in my data. How can I do this more easily? When I use group by twice, I feel like I'm doing code duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is use `sum` for `count` `True`s per `Gender`, so first convert `Gender` to index and then use `cum` per `level=0`, here per `Gender`:

```
survey = survey.set_index('Gender')
m1 = (survey.Gender == 'Man') | (survey.Gender == 'Woman')
m2 = survey.Occupation == 'Currently not employed'

(m1 & m2).sum(level=0)*100/m1.sum(level=0)
```